# Can Base64 be seen as a way of encryption if we use different index table?

Tags: algorithm-design

As we know, the index table (which maps bytes in [0, 63] to characters) of Base64 encoding is public, so everyone can decode Base64 strings from others.

But what if we use a shuffled index table and keep it secret? Can we see Base64 with this new table as some sort of safe encryption, and the shuffled table as cipher?

Comment: Did you see permutation cipher? Some sort of frequency attack will be possible. But there is no security against known plaintext attack.

Comment: @kelalaka actually this is a _substitution cipher_ as the ciphertext is not an anagram of the plaintext.

Comment: @SEJPM yes, the correct term, thanks. Modulo 24-bit, the conversion bits (6 vs 8) fits. If we arrange the ciphertext column-wise, the frequency attack must be still working.

Comment: See also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62425/decrypt-base64-encoded-monoalphabetic-cipher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we see Base64 with this new table as some sort of [..] encryption [...]?

Yes, technically it does constitute a form of encryption as knowledge of a secret key is required to recover plaintext from ciphertext.

> Can we see Base64 with this new table as some sort of **safe** encryption [...]?

**NO!** This is essentially a [monoalphabetic substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) applied on the Base64 encoded data. This can be seen as you can always take your table $T$ and then find a new $T'$ that undoes the base64 table encoding first and then applied after standard Base64 encoding.

Now while the key size is (theoretically) respectable with $\log_2 (64!)\approx 296$ bit, this cipher suffers from all the usual problems such ciphers have, including:

- Ciphertext-only attacks are possible using frequency analysis, as there are only 64 valid plaintext values and they will probably occur with different frequencies.
- Known- and chosen plaintext attacks are devastating as there are only 64 mappings to be uncovered and usually plaintexts have quite a bit of structure allowing to guess the rest / uncover significant parts of the plaintext.